# Update model field with button Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, controller, field

I have a messaging system in my Rails 5 project where the Message model has an `isread` field to indicate whether the recipient has read the message yet or not.

I'm using a bootstrap modal to view the message and would like the message's `isread` field to change to true when the modal is closed.

Could someone explain how to do this from the button_tag or make the button tag call method in the controller to do it?

Something like:

```
message.isread = true
message.save!
```

to execute when the "Close" button is pressed from my view:

```
<div id="modal1<%= index %>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><%= message.subject %></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><%= message.content %></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= button_tag "Close", :class => "btn btn-default", "data-dismiss" => "modal" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new action in your controller which update the attribute `isread` to true and use the `button_to` helper

```
#routes
resources :messages do
  post :is_read, on: :member
end  

#messages controller
def is_read
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  @message.update(isread: true)
  redirect_to ...
end

#view
<%= button_to "Close", is_read_message_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button click to call a method in your controller you will need to first capture the action of the button click in `javascript`

```
$(".btn-default").click(function(){

});
```

Then you want to do an Ajax call to the controller method

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/message/update_is_read",
    type: "POST",
    data: {is_read: isRead},
    success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);  
    },
    error: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    },
});
```

then in your controller catch it with

```
def update_is_read
     is_read = params[:is_read]

end
```

Make sure you make add the path to your routes

```
  post '/messages/update_is_read', to: 'messages#update_is_read', as: '/messages/update_is_read'
```

You can modify the controller code to save.